# Realm java (android) Compound Predicate

Tags: android, realm

How can I perform compound query in `Realm.android-0.88.2`?

In SQL the syntax would be like this:

```
select * from table1 where (a < x & b > y) or (a > x & b < y)
```

Please provide pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
realm.where(Table1.class)
          .beginGroup()
          .lowerThan("a", x)
          .greaterThan("b", y)
          .endGroup()
          .or()
          .beginGroup()
          .greaterThan("a", x)
          .lowerThan("b", y)
          .endGroup()
          .findAll();
```